# No bibliography output

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, rstudio

**Code**

```
\usepackage{babelbib}
```

...

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{LV}
```

I'm getting no output (bibliography). Installing the bibtex dependencies again for tex-live with no results. How to proceed?

The document is written in, and compiled from, RStudio.

---

Using `\cite{...}` works, but for each article which is not cited `\cite{Article_i}` has to be inserted in the document to create the bibliography (the bbl file). After it all unnecessary citations (`\cite{Article_i}`) have to be deleted and a new compilation the bibliography is inserted to the document.

Do you have any idea how to use `\nocite{*}` not to go the way using \cite?

Comment: Have you run `pdflatex`, then  `bibtex`, then `pdflatex` twice?

Comment: I'm using R Studio and converting the document automatically using the button "Compile PDF". I dont know if bibtex is executed.

Comment: Well, you have to run bibtex. I don't know anything about RStudio though, so I have no idea how to make it do that.  If you don't get an answer here, try at some RStudio-specific forum or similar (and if you get an answer elsewhere, consider adding an answer to this question yourself).

Comment: I tried to do the steps described at http://texblog.org/2013/08/20/rknitr-automatic-bibliography-generation-with-biblatex-in-rstudio/ and other descriptions but with no better results